# EthOS mining rig stops working after adding RX 560 GPU and only work with one brand of GPU

Tags: mining, rig, ethos

I have a mining rig with ASUS EV-B250-V7 MB with 6 GPU, initially only with 3 GTX 1050 TI GPU with EthOS 1.2.9 on USB 3.0 flash drive. The rig has been running for about a week without any problem.  But after adding 3 RX 560 cards, there are bunch of I/O error and the rig stops working. However if only 3 RX 560 GPUs or 3 GTX 1050 TI are plugged in, then the rig works fine. The problem happens when mixing both brand together. Is this configuration issue on EthOS? How to make 2 brand GPU work together?

Comment: `Mixing AMD/NVIDIA in the same rig (they use different drivers that cannot work together).` Here is the statement from EthOS. Not officially supported. Is there a way to get around it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

EthOS does not support both AMD and NVIDIA cards on the same rig.  It never will.  As far as I'm aware, none of the linus or ubuntu builds do.  Windows 10 supports up to 8 of both, but usually with a drop in performance, and difficulty with individual card settings.

Follow directions at http://ethosdistro.com/kb/#support for any additional questions.